# Keeping a table same width despite missing lines

Tags: tables, xetex

I'm crafting a custom command for a table that has optional lines but needs to be formatted consistently across the document (there are many instances).

The problem I'm running into is that when the table doesn't reach the maximum number of columns, the multi-column commands seem to get ignored and the table compacts to a smaller width.

Here is a demonstration, the second table takes up the entire line width (correct), but the first one, despite only missing one line compacts to a much shorter width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|m{\dimexpr.22\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}|m{\dimexpr.30\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}|m{\dimexpr.45\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}|}
\hline
\rowcolor{black!80} \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textcolor{white}{label}} \\
\hline
line1 & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{content} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|m{\dimexpr.22\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}|m{\dimexpr.30\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}|m{\dimexpr.45\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}|}
\hline
\rowcolor{black!80} \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textcolor{white}{label}} \\
\hline
line1 & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{content} \\
\hline
line2 & content1 & content2 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: The issue is that you're using `l` in your `\multicolumn`, you could instead use `\multicolumn{2}{m{\dimexpr.75\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}|}{content}`. Also your First `\multicolumn` misses the `|`, and could also use `\multicolumn{3}{m{.97\textwidth-\tabcolsep}|}` instead. Also note that as soon as you load the `array` package you'll also have to consider the `\arrayrulewidth` for each vertical rule to get the full width of your table.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` is a solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{NiceTabular}{X[22]X[30]X[48]}[hvlines]
\Block[l,fill=black!80]{1-*}{\color{white}\sffamily label} \\
line1 & \Block[l]{1-2}{content} & \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{NiceTabular}{X[22]X[30]X[48]}[hvlines]
\Block[l,fill=black!80]{1-*}{\color{white}\sffamily label} \\
line1 & \Block[l]{1-2}{content} & \\
line2 & content1 & content2 \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]